# Show dialog/frame fullscreen on a second screen sing QT/c++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, multiple-monitors

I have an application with a secondary view that should be shown fullscreen on the other monitor (the one the main app is not on).

Displaying the frame works quite well with `frame.showFullScreen();`

But, how can I tell it which screen it should be on? 
Is there a way to detect if a second screen is avauilable, as well?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can retrieve screen information from [QDesktopWidget](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qdesktopwidget.html). To move a window to a specific screen, you can do something like this:

```
QRect screenres = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry(screenNumber);
widget->move(QPoint(screenres.x(), screenres.y()));
```

Comment: This sounds just like what I wanted! I'll try it.